# Is there such a thing as a decentralized stock market desktop application, in concept similar to Bisq?

Tags: decentralization, p2p, decentralized-assets, decentralized-exchanges, stocks

Please note that I've already visited thousands upon thousands of slick websites with fuzzy claims about being "the future of money" and I consider them all to be vaporware at best, and usually downright scams. I have no use for yet another such URL where all I get is the same nonsensical word salad but nothing that can actually be downloaded and used today, right now.

Is there such a thing as a **currently launched**, **in-use**, decentralized trading desktop application? That is, not a centralized website with "Register" and "Log in" on it, not "Open in App Store", not "Available for your Android phone", but an **actual program** that is downloaded, installed, run, and which then functions like Bisq, but instead, you can trade on stocks with zero KYC/AML BS, zero registration of any accounts, zero any BS except that you have to back up a file on your computer. Like I already do with Bitcoin Core and Bisq. But for trading stocks and perhaps other financial instruments, in a tokenized digital form which has nothing to do with the "traditional" stock market.

My guess/hunch is that this "is being worked on", but is not actually available yet.

Just like in Bisq, I would expect it to require me to initially send in some satoshis to my "wallet" inside of the application, which is then locked while used as some kind of internal tokens until I withdraw the BTC back to my own wallet. (If I have any left after making actual trades.)

As you might have guessed, I've extensively searched for this myself before asking here, and only found the kind of "word salad" fake websites which offer nothing but empty claims of being "the future".

Comment: *'not "Open in App Store", not "Available for your Android phone", but an **actual program**'* — are iOS and Android apps not "actual programs"?